# get error in solr copyField dest :'textnge' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField

Tags: solr, tomcat7

I have an issue in solr schema file, i got an error in solr, see my schema file

```
<field name="Name" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
   <field name="NameCopy" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="false" />


<copyField source="NameCopy" dest="textnge"/>
        <field name="textnge" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" />   
        <copyField source="NameCopy" dest="textng"/>
        <field name="textng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />  
        <copyField source="NameCopy" dest="textphon"/>
```

Error message:-

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: copyField dest :'textnge' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.. Schema file is c:\solr\InfiniteScroll\schema.xml
```

How to solve this issue,
my solr version is 4.6

Please suggest me

Regards,
vinit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Your field definitions are *not* inside <fields> section and are not being picked up by Solr. That requirement goes away in later Solr (4.8 I think), but for now you need those sections
2. You have another error in your log somewhere that makes the XML file not processed properly. Try opening the schema file in an XML editor (or a browser) and see if there are any validation complaints.